# Как сделать, чтобы текст не выделялся

Tags: html, css, javascript

У меня есть див, на нем обработчик `onclick`, но на диве есть текст и он иногда выделяется. Как сделать чтобы не выделялся? Желательно через css.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.unselectable {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

- [5. Как запретить выделение текста на JS?](http://habrahabr.ru/post/124327/)

Answer (score 6):

```
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-o-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function disableSelection(target){
if (typeof target.onselectstart!="undefined")
    target.onselectstart=function(){return false}
else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect!="undefined")
    target.style.MozUserSelect="none"
else
    target.onmousedown=function(){return false}
target.style.cursor = "default"
}

//Пример:
//disableSelection(document.body);
//disableSelection(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйся этим:

```
<span onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false"> Элементы, которые не должны выделяться мышью </span>
```

Пример:

```
<span onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false">
<a id="minus" onclick="minus()" class="hvr-border-fade"> - </a></span>

<input readonly="true" name="qty" id="qty" style="width:50px;text-align:center" value="1000">

<span onselectstart="return false" onmousedown="return false"><a id="plus" onclick="plus()" class="hvr-border-fade"> + </a> <br/></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

В CSS

```
."класс div"{user-select: none;}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]